# Parent child query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have collection with this data :

```
[
  {
    _id: "id1",
    parentId: null,
    text: "text 1"
  },
  {
    _id: "id2",
    parentId: null,
    text: "text 2"
  },
  {
    _id: "id3",
    parentId: null,
    text: "text 3"
  },
  {
    _id: "id4",
    parentId: "id1",
    text: "text 4"
  },
  {
    _id: "id5",
    parentId: "id1",
    text: "text 5"
  },
  {
    _id: "id6",
    parentId: "id2",
    text: "text 6"
  },
  {
    _id: "id7",
    parentId: "id5",
    text: "text 7"
  }
]
```

I want every child to come after its parent like this :

```
[
  {
    _id: "id1",
    parentId: null,
    text: "text 1"
  },
  {
    _id: "id4",
    parentId: "id1",
    text: "text 4"
  },
  {
    _id: "id5",
    parentId: "id1",
    text: "text 5"
  },
  {
    _id: "id7",
    parentId: "id5",
    text: "text 7"
  },
  {
    _id: "id2",
    parentId: null,
    text: "text 2"
  },
  {
    _id: "id6",
    parentId: "id2",
    text: "text 6"
  },
  {
    _id: "id3",
    parentId: null,
    text: "text 3"
  }
]
```

but I didn't find any query for this in mongodb . Is that possible ?
I use this schema for store comments and I need to sort like that.
for sql query I found this video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yA-YqKBNyNc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using aggregate framework :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        parentIdId: {
            $concat: [{
                $ifNull: [{
                    $toString: "$parentId"
                }, ""]
            }, {
                $toString: "$_id"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        parentIdId: 1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        parentIdId: 0
    }
}])
```

The result :

```
{"_id":"id1","parentId":null,"text":"text 1","parentIdId":"id1"}
{"_id":"id4","parentId":"id1","text":"text 4","parentIdId":"id1id4"}
{"_id":"id5","parentId":"id1","text":"text 5","parentIdId":"id1id5"}
{"_id":"id2","parentId":null,"text":"text 2","parentIdId":"id2"}
{"_id":"id6","parentId":"id2","text":"text 6","parentIdId":"id2id6"}
{"_id":"id3","parentId":null,"text":"text 3","parentIdId":"id3"}
{"_id":"id7","parentId":"id5","text":"text 7","parentIdId":"id5id7"}
```

In this solution, I create a new field in your query result that is the concatenation of parentId and Id and, then I sort on it.

If you want to remove this technical field, you can add this pipeline stage :

```
{$project: {parentIdId: 0}}
```

Your final query would be :

```
db.test.aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        parentIdId: {
            $concat: [{
                $ifNull: [{
                    $toString: "$parentId"
                }, ""]
            }, {
                $toString: "$_id"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
        parentIdId: 1
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        parentIdId: 0
    }
}])
```

Comment: Thank you , I run your query but I got this error: ``` $concat only supports strings, not objectId" ```

Comment: You can use `$toString`. I add it to the answer

Comment: I add that but I got this error: Unrecognized expression '$toString

Comment: Fixed in the answer

Comment: Thank you , but I have still this error :  Unrecognized expression '$toString

Comment: my current version is  v3.6.3

Comment: Erf that’s why. $toString us only for mongodb 4+ :/

Comment: None that I know :/

Comment: in the last result item "parentId":"id5" but it come after _id= "id3" , is it possible to come last result after its parent ?

Comment: Erf, it is possible but way more complicated. We need a $grephLookup stage, but it will clearly degrade query performances.

Comment: I just add another field `path` and I sort by this , this field store a string like this: "id1/id2/id3/" and I get parent child result but I want to add another sort to this result like sort by date & I want to remain parent-child structure . is that possible ?